# Is it possible to present an un-editable SMS to the user using MFMessageComposeViewController?

Tags: ios

Is it possible to compose an SMS that when presented to the user for confirmation cannot have its body text deleted or altered?

Comment: Not using MFMessageComposeViewController. For that to happen you would have to build a backend that sends the SMS on behalf of the user.

Comment: Or use private API's to send the message...